# How to handle VK_MENU (alt) keypresses properly using WinAPI?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am writing a windows application using the WinAPI (win32) on C++, but can't figure out what's happening with the ALT key. I am handling both WM_KEYDOWN and WM_SYSKEYDOWN, so all keypresses should be coming through. However, while every ALT keyup is detected, every second ALT keydown is being skipped.

Do I have to generate my own keydown event whenever I get a second WM_SYSKEYUP in a row, or am I doing something wrong with my message handling?

**Details**

Tap these keys: `ALT ALT ALT ALT ALT` (alt five times)
Expected message sequence: `DUDUDUDUDU` (down then up, repeated five times)
Observed message sequence: `DUUDUUDU` (every second down is missing)

Tap these keys: `ALT C ALT C ALT C ALT C ALT C` (add other keypresses in between - release ALT before tapping C)
Expected VK_MENU message sequence: `DUDUDUDUDU` (down then up, repeated five times)
Observed VK_MENU message sequence: `DUDUDUDUDU` (as expected!)

It seems that adding other keypresses (or even mouse events) cancels whatever Windows was doing and forces it to send the app all the ALT keypresses.

**Example code (Visual c++17):**

Creates a window which adds 'D' to the window title when ALT is pressed and 'U' when ALT is released

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define NOMINMAX
#define STRICT
#include <Windows.h>
#include <optional>
#include <malloc.h>

WCHAR* title;
int titleLen = 0;
const int maxTitleLen = 64;

void updateWindowTitle(WCHAR c, HWND hwnd)
{
    if (titleLen >= maxTitleLen) return;
    title[titleLen++] = c;
    title[titleLen] = 0;
    SetWindowTextW(hwnd, title);
}

LRESULT WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    case WM_SYSKEYDOWN: //needed for keys like alt (VK_MENU)
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        //process_keydown_event(wParam);
        if (!(lParam & 0x40000000)) { //ignore autorepeat
            if (wParam == VK_MENU) updateWindowTitle(L'D', hwnd);
        }
        break;
    case WM_SYSKEYUP: //needed for keys like alt (VK_MENU)
    case WM_KEYUP:
        //process_keyup_event(wParam);
        if (wParam == VK_MENU) updateWindowTitle(L'U', hwnd);
        break;
    //etc...
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

// *********** STANDARD BORING SETUP BELOW ************

std::optional<int> processMessages() noexcept
{
    MSG msg;
    while (PeekMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
        {
            // Return argument to PostQuitMessage as we are quitting
            return msg.wParam;
        }
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return {}; //return empty optional when not quitting
}

int CALLBACK WinMain(
    HINSTANCE hInst,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInst,
    LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
    int       nShowCmd)
{
    // Make global title point to valid memory
    title = static_cast<WCHAR*>(malloc(sizeof(WCHAR) * maxTitleLen));

    // Register window class
    WNDCLASSEX wc = { 0 };
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_OWNDC;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInst;
    wc.hIcon = nullptr;
    wc.hIconSm = nullptr;
    wc.hCursor = nullptr;
    wc.hbrBackground = nullptr;
    wc.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"my window class name";
    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    // Create window 800x500
    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowW(
        wc.lpszClassName, L"",
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 800, 500,
        nullptr, nullptr, hInst, nullptr
    );
    // (check HWND is not NULL)

    //main loop
    while (true)
    {
        if (const auto errorcode = processMessages())
        {
            return errorcode.value();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ALT is used for many system commands. Using WM_SYSKEYDOWN is usually not a good idea. If you want to determine if ALT was pressed in your context you can use GetKeyState/GetAsyncKeyState https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811206/on-win32-how-to-detect-whether-a-left-shift-or-right-alt-is-pressed-using-perl PS: you message pump eats the CPU, here is the official sample: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-messages-and-message-queues#creating-a-message-loop

Comment: I assume you have already determined that you have a valid reason to override default SYSKEYDOWN behavior (that includes F10 too). I remember there being several gotchas about this... Afaik libraries like SDL do pretty much what you did (its source code is probably a good place to start looking). At first glance I think it might help if you *don't* call `DefWindowProc` (i.e. replace your `break` with `return 0`). Because normally VK_MENU puts the application in a "system menu mode", it'll respond differently to messages then. Please try that and see if it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem through code, and then I capture the message of the window through spy++.

We can see that when the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key is pressed for the first time, the `WM_SYSKEYDOWN` and `WM_SETTEXT` messages are successfully triggered:

[image]

When the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key is pressed the second time, it actually triggers the `WM_SYSKEYDOWN` message, but after a series of message sending(`WM_CAPTURECHANGED`,`WM_MENUSELECT`...).This resulted in the message not being processed in the main window, but sent to `hmenu:00000000`, so the main window did not process the `WM_SYSKEYDOWN` message.

[image]

You can handle it by processing the `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message:

```
case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
    if (wParam == SC_KEYMENU)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    break;
```

It works for me.

Comment: Hi,if this answer did help to you, please feel free to mark it to help people with the same issue, and let me know if you have any problem.Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, your solution definitely works. Although it's disabling default behaviour, that's fine in my case as my application doesn't have or need a system menu. Sorry I took a while to reply!